# If on URL then message box

Tags: vb.net, message, credentials

So I have this weird problem. I have a WebBrowser starting on the page https://live.xbox.com/en-US/MyXbox/GamerProfile (It is a page for editing information on your account) but whenever it goes there it takes the user to live.com to log in, and then goes back to the page to edit his profile. This is how I want it to function, but I want a message box to display if it takes the user to the page again (to verify he's logged in). This is what I have so far:

```
 If WebBrowser1.Url.OriginalString() = "https://live.xbox.com/en-US/MyXbox/GamerProfile" Then  

        MessageBox.Show("You are logged in!")
  End If
```

But I never get the message box to show, and I don't think it works :\
Does anyone know why it isn't working?

Comment: Where is this code located? Can you show it in context? Have you set a breakpoint there to test whether it is ever actually executed?

Answer (score 0):

which part of your application is that code running?  I mean, does your program knows when xbox takes the webrowser to the login page and back?  If your code only run once when the webbrowser object is created, then this doesn't get run.

**EDIT:**
In that case, the code should be within the WebBrwoser.`DocumentCompleted()` event. Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx

Comment: Well I don't really know where to put this. I put it under webbrowser1 but I think it actually should go under the button1 (the submit button to login)